# Swift - Result.Success Extra argument in call

Tags: swift, completion

I have the following function

```
func refreshFeedItems(completion: @escaping ActivityFeedCompletion) {
    let currentTab = feedTab
    //Result<([FeedItem], Bool)>) -> Void
    // Load the cache in and start the spinner for the network request we're about to make
    completion(.success(cache[currentTab], true))
    ActivityFeedService.sharedInstance.refreshCommunityFeed(tab: currentTab) { result in
        // A quick user might switch tabs before this
        // call completes since we call completion twice
        guard currentTab == self.feedTab else {
            return
        }
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            Log.warn(error)
            completion(.failure(error))
        case .success(let items):
            self.cache[self.feedTab] = items
            let tuple = Result.success(items,true) as ActivityFeedCompletion
           completion((tuple,false))
        }
    }
}
```

But this line

```
completion(.success(cache[currentTab], true))
```

and this one

```
let tuple = Result.success(items,true) as ActivityFeedCompletion
```

Both throw me an "Extra argument in call" error.

This is my acticvity completion typealias

```
typealias ActivityFeedCompletion = (Result<([FeedItem], Bool)>) -> Void
```

I am not sure why I am getting that error, I think it is misleading but I ran out of ideas of what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The second error is pretty clear (the bridge cast is most likely redundant)

```
let tuple = Result.success(items,true) //  as ActivityFeedCompletion
```

represents already the result so you have to write

```
completion(tuple)
```

The first error is probably something similar, it's unclear what `cache` is

Comment: Thank you! But once I fix that second error. The instruction completion(tuple) throws the same error as the first one. Which is what I've been trying desperately to work around.

Comment: The cache is the following.                                                                              fileprivate let cache = ActivityFeedCache.shared .                                                                 static let shared = ActivityFeedCache()
    private init() {
        fetchFromDefaults()
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding many relevant parts of your code, so I needed to fill many parts by guess. If my answer is far from what you expect, you should better update your question and show relevant parts of your code. For example, whole definition of your `ActivityFeedCache`.

---

With this definition:

```
typealias ActivityFeedCompletion = (Result<([FeedItem], Bool)>) -> Void
```

The success case of the `Result` of your `ActivityFeedCompletion` takes a **single** argument of tuple type `([FeedItem], Bool)`.

In this line:

```
completion(.success(cache[currentTab], true))
```

You are passing two arguments, to `success`, so the message is clear enough. You need to pass a **single** argument.

```
completion(.success((cache[currentTab], true)))
```

And the latter part:

```
let tuple = Result.success(items,true) as ActivityFeedCompletion
completion((tuple,false))
```

You are completely mistaking the types. `Result` cannot be converted to `ActivityFeedCompletion`, and you cannot pass a raw tuple `(tuple,false)` to `completion` which takes `Result<([FeedItem], Bool)>`.

Please try something like this:

```
completion(.success((items, true/* or false, which you want to pass? */)))
```